# Efficient Queue with batching

Tags: python, go, queue, channel, job-batching

I want to implement an internal Queue for batch processing in my service. The client of my service would be making sequential calls with 1 element at a time and I would like to process multiple of them at once internally if I have them available. This will help me scale for the bulk operation case where requests are submitted in parallel. However, I would like to not slow down the sequential case by adding some artificial delays waiting for potential new requests and batching them. This artificial delay value is hard to come up with and also requires a lot of fine-tuning to make sure we don't do a busy poll and that performance for both sequential and parallel cases is reasonable.

In Python, I would do something like

```
BATCHS_SIZE = 100

def drain_queue():
  ev = ev_queue.get()
  evs = []
  evs.append(ev)
  while True:
    if len(evs) == BATCH_SIZE:
      break
    try:
      ev = ev_queue.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
      break
    evs.append(ev)
  process_evs(evs)
```

I am looking for a similar solution for Golang, possibly using channels. This is the current solution I came up with:

```
dur := time.Duration(1000) * time.Millisecond // 1 second wait.
for msg := range evQueue {
  // Start a new batch with this message.
  batch := []BatchArg{msg}
  timedOut := false
  // Loop until the batch is full or a time out.
  for timeout := time.After(dur); len(batch) < 200 && !timedOut; {
    select {
    case other := <-evQueue:
      batch = append(batch, other)
    case <-timeout:
      // The batching channel is empty, and the timer ticked.
      timedOut = true
    }
  }
  processBatch(batch)
}
```

But this adds an artificial delay of 1 second in the sequential case. The caller side adds to the queue in Python and the channel in Golang.

Comment: The try/except block in Python translates directly to a select statement with a default case in Go. Simply replace `case <-timeout:` with `default:` and you have a non-blocking receive operation: https://go.dev/play/p/Tzm1dBLyCvK

Comment: @CharlieTumahai the aim is to process each element as fast as possible but process more than 1 (up to N) they are available in the queue.